# performance of data.table for summary statistics on smaller datasets

Tags: r, data.table

When using data.table `j` notation to compute summary statistics for an entire column (without by-group processing) on smaller datasets (say 100,000 rows or less), performance seems unexpectedly slow, compared to directly accessing elements:

```
library(microbenchmark)
library(data.table)
df <- data.frame(x=rnorm(10000, 0, 0.05))
dt <- data.table(df)

microbenchmark(prod(df$x + 1)^(12 / NROW(df)) - 1,
               prod(dt$x + 1)^(12 / NROW(dt)) - 1,
               dt[,prod(x + 1)^(12 / .N) - 1], times=10000)

Unit: microseconds
                             expr     min       lq      mean   median       uq
 prod(df$x + 1)^(12/NROW(df)) - 1  51.210  58.0725  85.34422  62.0715  69.8885
 prod(dt$x + 1)^(12/NROW(dt)) - 1  68.514  76.4710 107.49639  80.6950  89.5425
    dt[, prod(x + 1)^(12/.N) - 1] 777.879 829.9515 951.92379 852.7325 916.0155
```

Is this something to be expected, or perhaps I am not using data.table correctly, or missing some options?

Comment: Don't use 10k iterations, use a larger data set. If I use `df <- data.frame(x=rnorm(1e7, 0, 0.05))` with `times=10`, it is clear that they take about the same time. The only difference you see comes from, yes, the fact that `[.data.table` does have some overhead cost.

Comment: Indeed, it seems to about break even at 1 million rows, so there appears to be a somewhat fixed overhead. I've edited the question to reflect that. The question is, is there a way to avoid these overhead costs, or is it better to avoid using `[.data.table` syntax altogether in some cases, such as when it is used inside a function that is being called multiple times on a number of smaller datasets.

Comment: Ok. Even in that case, it's still microseconds (...gonna edit that in...). I guess if you're working with some online application used by millions of people, it might matter...? It's not an issue I can imagine coming across in my normal stats work.

Comment: It's called within an iterative procedure that algorithmically generates a lot of these small datasets. It's not a major issue at this point, but since I am not really a data.table expert, I was wondering if I was missing something.